# Open a link in new tab and trigger postback in the current tab

Tags: javascript, html, django, post, hyperlink

I want to dislay a link button that, when clicked, triggers postback in the current tab and opens a link in new tab.
If it matters, the backend is Python Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitAndOpen() {
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" id="form1">
    <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank" onclick="return submitAndOpen()">
        Submit and open in new tab
    </a>
</form>
```

So returning `true` in `onclick` says the browser to follow the link.

`target="_blank"` says to open the link in a new tab.

The JavaScript function also submits the form.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
<a href="YourRout" target="_blank" onclick='return check()'>check</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function check()
{
    return false;
}

</script>
```

**target="_blank"** will open in new tab

**onClick="method()"** will set postback in current tab

Comment: does it make difference whether you write `return check()` or `check()` as it's just onClick.

Comment: So does it mean that returning `false` from `onclick` method submits the form?

Comment: @SergeRogatch It's just sample code. Don't focus on what's inside the function.